# Why SELECT COUNT(*) performs clustered index scan?

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, clustered-index

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addr](
    [Address] [char](34) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Addr] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Address] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I am trying to execute a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Addr
```

When table contains about 8 million records, it was executing immediately. But now table contains 21 million records, and query is executing very slow. Managemet Studio shows the next estimated plan:

[image: Execution plan]

Screenshot from Storage tab (Table Properties):

[image]

I am using `MSSQL 2008 Express 10.50.1617.0`. Why this simple query has such complicated plan?

Comment: Probably revealing my own ignorance of SQL Server here, but what plan do you get for `select count(Address) from Addr`? (I'll be *shocked* if they're different, just curious.)

Comment: Plan is the same as `select count(Address) from Addr`

Comment: Could it be that the table has now been partitioned?

Comment: How slowly is "very slow"? You may also be encountering blocking from other transactions. Particularly if it never seems to finish at all that may well be the case.

Comment: "very slow" - I am waiting for 3 minutes, and after that terminate a query. There is not other transactions.

Comment: 3 minutes to read 10GB of data seems fairly slow but not impossible. Have you checked in `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID('Addr')` to be sure there are no conflicting locks?

Comment: I ran your query, there is no conflicting locks. Why you are saying about 10GB, data space in only 1 GB

Comment: @Zergatul - Ah I see. I guess you are in a locale where `,` is the decimal separator not thousands!

Comment: In that case 3 minutes to read 1GB of data does seem painfully slow. BTW What is "Address"? Is it postal address? If so `[char](34)` seems a really odd choice. It will always store 34 characters even if the address is actually much shorter. You could possibly reduce the size of the table and IO significantly if you switch to `varchar`.

Comment: No, that is bitcoin address, that has constant (plus-minus 1) length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plan is not complicated at all. To count the number of records, the engine has to scan entire table, but since there's a clustered index, it uses it. With no clustered index, thre would be `Table Scan` instead of `Clustered Index Scan`. If you had non-clustered index on any column, the optimizer would most probably choose that index to count the records, and the operation would be faster.

Comment: But how to explain, when table contained 8 million records, this query was executing immediately?

Comment: @Zergatul: Perhaps you've crossed the point where the index fits in memory.

Comment: @Zergatul - Probably the pages were all in cache then. It still would have had a CI scan counting 8 million rows.

Comment: That is interesting. Is there any ways to check this?

Comment: @Zergatul `SET STATISTICS IO ON` then run your query. I see you are on Express Edition so that is limited to 1GB of data cache and also doesn't use read ahead to bring pages into cache. Also you could check the level of fragmentation on the CI and defrag if needed. Might give some improvement.

Comment: @Adam, why using non-clustered index for Count operation would be faster than clustered one?

Comment: You mean to tell me that the database doesn't just track the number of rows and actually has to inspect individual pages every time it wants a count?